# Google Map and Geocomplete at the same Page Does not work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am using a Google Map in a page - with 2 Markers and a the route between those markers.

And there is one GeoComplete also in the page.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

This is the included script for the GeoComplete,

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is the included script for the Map.

The problem is , both of that does not work together. When I remove one library, one work, and the other does not.

This is the Geocomplete Code

```
                $("#point").geocomplete({country: "ARE"})
                .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result) {
                    $("#latpoint").val(result.geometry.location.ob);
                    $("#longpoint").val(result.geometry.location.pb);
                });
```

And this is the Map Code

```
var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
       var directions = new GDirections(map);
       var isCreateHeadPoint = true;
       var headMarker, tailMarker;

       map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.50, -0.12), 12);

       var point = new google.maps.LatLng(someLat, someLong);  
       headMarker = new GMarker(point); 
       map.addOverlay(headMarker);
       var point = new google.maps.LatLng(SomeotherLat, SomeotherLong);  
       tailMarker = new GMarker(point);
       map.addOverlay(tailMarker);

       directions.load("from:SomeLat,SomeLong to:SomeotherLat,SomeotherLong", 
                             { getPolyline: true, getSteps: true });
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the Geocomplete script? It looks very different from the [code here](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/docs/).

Comment: Update your map-code to V3 and you don't need to include both Maps-API's

Answer (score 1):

got this working when I used this Single Javascript include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```